# Java Database MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, sql

Hi in the following code it only prints the first id and the first name from the table. How do yo get it to print out all of the results from the query and not only the first results? thanks

```
Statement stat = conn.createStatement();  

stat.execute("CREATE TABLE Test (Id VARCHAR(20), Name VARCHAR(20))");  
stat.execute("INSERT INTO Test VALUES ('1AA', 'John')");  
stat.execute("INSERT INTO Test VALUES ('2AA', 'George')");
stat.execute("INSERT INTO Test VALUES ('3AA', 'Richard')");


ResultSet result = stat.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM Test");  
result.next();  
System.out.println(result.getString("Name"));  
System.out.println(result.getString("Id"));
stat.execute("DROP TABLE Test");
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a `while` loop to iterate over all results:

```
...
ResultSet result = stat.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM Test");  
while(result.next()) {  
    System.out.println(result.getString("Name"));  
    System.out.println(result.getString("Id"));
}
stat.execute("DROP TABLE Test");
```

Answer (score 2):

A `ResultSet` is an iterator, that is the `next` method provides an indication if there is more data present.

For instance:

```
while(result.next()) {
 System.out.println(result.getString("Name"));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to iterate through the result. You can use the `while` loop

```
 while(result.next())
 {  
        System.out.println(result.getString("Name"));  
        System.out.println(result.getString("Id"));
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You may iterate through the ResultSet to print all of the results from the query as shown below:

```
    stat.execute("CREATE TABLE Test (Id VARCHAR(20), Name VARCHAR(20))");  
    stat.execute("INSERT INTO Test VALUES ('1AA', 'John')");  
    stat.execute("INSERT INTO Test VALUES ('2AA', 'George')");
    stat.execute("INSERT INTO Test VALUES ('3AA', 'Richard')");


    ResultSet result = stat.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM Test");  

    while(result.next()) {
       System.out.println(result.getString("Name")+"\t"+result.getString("Id"));
       //OR
       //System.out.println(result.getString(1)+"\t"+result.getString(2));
    }

    stat.execute("DROP TABLE Test");
```